# Get error - Fatal Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

When I am executing the following code I get the error code described in the header:

```
function getBrands($b_showAll) {
    global $mysql;

    if($b_showAll==true) {
        $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM producer");
    }

    else {
        $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM producer WHERE (active = 1)");
    }

    $result = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
        $brand = new brand();
        $brand->name = $row['name'];
        $brand->logo = $row['logo'];
        $brand->active = $row['active'];
        array_push($result, $brand);
    }   
    return $result;
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess your query is not returning any results

Comment: `$query` is likely failing and returning FALSE. From the code posted, it is difficult to say why.

Comment: To solve this error you have to get the error from Mysql

Comment: By the way, you can create an object at once, like `while ($brand = $query->fetch_object('brand')) {$result[] = $brand;}`

Comment: And consider using PDO, as it will make your code just one line, `$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'brand');`